# Access to a set of records to a user

Tags: permissions, sharing, profile, permission-sets

I have to create a permission set for a user, where only when the Lead source is web, he/she should be able to view and edit that set of records.  Is this achievable by using permission set?

Answer (score 1):

Permission sets and profiles work in an identical fashion in that you can use them to configure Create/Read/Edit/Delete access to an entity, or to the fields in that entity.

But these features cannot be used to identify which users can access individual records of a given entity, except in two ways.

1. You can use a permission set or profile so that members can access *every* record for a given entity in a read-only fashion by using the "View All" checkbox.
2. You can use a permission set or profile so that members have **full access** to *every* record for a given entity by using the "Modify All" checkbox.

What you cannot do with permission sets or profiles is grant access to a *specific subset* of records.

In order to do so, you need to use the rules for record-level access which is controlled by the sharing model.

Fortunately there are excellent whitepapers to help newcomers understand the functioning of the sharing model. There is one on the [basic sharing architecture](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/A_Guide_to_Sharing_Architecture). There is another that gives [a more under-the-hood view of what goes on when sharing happens](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Record-Level_Access:_Under_the_Hood).

There is also the [security workbook](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook_security/index.htm), with hands-on exercises to you can build some test cases and understand how security works in the context of entity, field, and record access.

**Full Record Access:** To understand what I'm talking about above by "full access" and how that is distinguished from assigning all of the Create/Read/Edit/Delete access perms on an entity, you should read the Sharing Model whitepaper above and do the workbook. But I always remember this using the mnemonic: VESTeD. When you have full access, you are VESTeD meaning you have:

- View access to a given record
- Edit access to a given record
- Share access to a given record (you are permitted to manually share this record with other users who don't automatically have access).
- Transfer Access to a given record (transfer ownership of this record to another user).
- Delete access to a given record (normally, only owners and some other privileged users can delete records).